# Calculate influence of absolute risk aversion on consumption decisions

Tags: microeconomics, utility, consumer-theory, risk-aversion

Say I have the following setup:

A consumer chooses between two goods $x$ and $y$ (a numeraire) such that she maximises:
$$V(x,y)=u(x)+y$$
Under the constraint that her revenue $R$ is such that:
$$R\geq px+y$$
Where $p$ is the price of $x$. The first-order condition of this problem is:
$$u'(x)-p=0\qquad (1)$$
How does the consumption of $x$ vary with $A(x)=-\frac{u''(x)}{u'(x)}$, the measure of the consumer's absolute risk aversion? Let's first assume that the consumer exhibits constant absolute risk aversion (i.e. $A(x)=a$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}_+$) I would be tempted to do the following:

- First, rewrite expression (1) as below:
  $$\frac{-u''(x)}{A(x)}-p=0\Leftrightarrow \frac{-u''(x)}{a}-p=0\quad (2)$$
- Then, use the implicit function theorem and differentiate (2) with respect to $a$ to obtain:
  $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}=\frac{u''(x)}{u'''(x)a}$$
  Therefore, one can show that consumption decreases with a higher absolute level of risk aversion when $u'''(x)>0$.

I have two questions: is this proof correct? How can we generalise it to e.g. the case of decreasing absolute risk aversion?

Many thanks!